# General question regarding allocating memory for an integer in C

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am currently learning about dynamic memory allocation in C and am having difficulty with a particular concept. For using malloc for a particular integer, I need to put a previously declared integer within that space.

The following below is what I am putting in as my code.

```
void example(int ab)
{
int* intPtr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*intPtr = &ab;
}
```

I am not trying to run a program or anything. I just want to see if I have the right idea about some basic memory allocation.

Comment: Its not necessary to typecast the `malloc()` as it's done implicitly by compiler. Read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). This `int* intPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));` is fine.

Comment: `ab` already has a space on stack, In C memory to local variables is gets allocated on stack a static time in terms of offset from Sack pointer. You can read about Storage Classes in C for static memory allocation . Also you cannot change address of any variable in c in run-time.

Comment: Vagish that is true I have learned about the stack and how local variables are allocated. So if I was hypothetically declaring a new variable in this context would i do: *intPtr=int x?

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues, firstly its not necessary to typecast the result of `malloc()` as it's done implicitly by compiler. [Read Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). This

```
int* intPtr = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* or even malloc(sizeof(*intPtr)); is better */
```

is fine.

Secondly, this

```
*intPtr = &ab; /* *intPtr means value at allocated dynamic address, you should assign the value not address of ab*/
```

is wrong as `*intPtr` is the value at dynamic address, compiler should have warned you like

> main.c:7:9: warning: incompatible pointer to integer
>         conversion assigning to '`int`' from '`int *`'; **remove &**
>         [-Wint-conversion]

If you had compiled with below flags like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic test.c
```

It should be

```
*intPtr = ab;
```

Also you are not freeing the dynamically allocated memory, its leads to memory leakage. Free the dynamically allocated memory  by calling `free()` once usage is done.

**Side note**, if your intention is to do like this

```
intPtr = &ab; /* Before this statement intPtr was pointing dynamic memory(heap), but now that gets overwritten with stack allocated space */
```

then you are *overwriting dynamic memory with stack created memory i.e address of local variable*, in that case you are loosing dynamic memory as nothing is pointing to previously allocated dynamic address.

Comment: Thanks that clears up some misconceptions I was having. I also was type casting because I read some prior examples that did type casting when using malloc. I  will read the resource you posted above.

Comment: @NoobCoder: Prior to the 1989 standard, `malloc` returned `char *`, so a cast *was* required if you wanted to assign the result to a different pointer type.  The ‘89 standard changed `malloc` to return `void *`, which can be assigned to other pointer types without the cast.  This is not the case in C++, which does not allow direct assignment between `void *` and other pointer types.